# Bloomberg function quotes causing run-time errors

Tags: excel, vba, loops, bloomberg

When trying to execute the below code, I get the error "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error".

I am trying to get this formula into a multitude of cells if they are empty:

```
=BDP(B1 & " Muni", "CPN")
```

With the 1 in "A1" being the output of the loop-defined variable r which represents row #, column letter is static.

```
Sub Add_BBG_Coupons()

Dim r As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim BDP1 As String
Dim BDP2 As String
Dim strQuote As String


wSheets = Array("ACTHXSortNeg", "ACTHXSortPos", "ISHAXSortPos", "ISHAXSortNeg")

For I = LBound(wSheets) To UBound(wSheets)
    With Worksheets(wSheets(I)).Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 4)) = True Then
            Cells(r, 4).Select
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=BDP(B" & r & " Muni"",""CPN"")"
            End If
        Next r
    End With 
Next I

End Sub
```

I am able to get `=BDP(A1 & Muni,CPN)` into the cell, but when I use double quotes here and there to try and get `=BDP(B1 & " Muni", "CPN")` , I receive the above error.

I have tried setting a variable to `Chr(34)` as well as `Chr(38)` and concatenating but then I get object defined errors.

Comment: Its not a duplicate because I have tried those remedies and it does not work - if someone else can use this remedy with my code and get it to run please let me know.

Comment: `"=BDP(B" & r & "& "" Muni"",""CPN"")"`

Comment: @BigBen I missed the `&`, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub testsub()
With Range("a1")
    .Formula = "=BDP(B" & r & " & " & Chr(34) & " Muni" & Chr(34) & ", " & Chr(34) & "CPN" & Chr(34) & ")"
End With
End Sub
```

This should work. You don't concatanate chr() you use it as a variable with tonnes of variations at the end of its name. So to add it into your formula use `"sometext " & chr(34) & " somemoretext"` this will print as `sometext " somemoretext`